# Cannot quite figure out how to change "more" tab's navbar color; in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, navbar

I have a few tabs set up and there are just enough of them to require a more tab.

The more tab; however does not seem to have the same navbar coloration as my other tabs do.

From what I discovered from other searches the only way to do this is by writing:

```
UINavigationController* moreBar = self.tabBarControlelrVC.moreNavigationController;
moreBar.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

I put that in my `viewDidLoad` of my appDelegate; but to no avail...

anyone got any good posts or ideas on this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to set it like so:

in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
tabBarController = (UITabBarController *) self.window.rootViewController;

 // Set the color of the navigationbar in moretab
 UINavigationController *moreBar = tabBarController.moreNavigationController;
 moreBar.navigationBar.barStyle = UIBarStyleBlack;
```

or the other properties...

```
 moreBar.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
 moreBar.navigationBar.hidden = NO;
 moreBar.navigationBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
```

Comment: Yes, still in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Did that work for you?

Comment: Yea that worked; I just never declared an instance of the tabBarController that was my mistake. :) Thanks buddy!